# Re-Ordering a Custom Post Type Query performed by Directorist Plugin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, plugins

First of all, I appologize in advance for my ignorance. I am trying to re-order a listing plugin's WP_Query by the id of a meta value called "_fm_plans" using the 'pre_get_posts' action in functions.php. The original query looks liek this in the plugin's folder:

```
$args = array(
                    'post_type'      => ATBDP_POST_TYPE,
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                    'post_status'    => 'public',
                    'meta_query'     => array(
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                        array(
                            'key'   => '_listing_status',
                            'value' => 'post_status',
                        ),
                        array(
                            'key'   => '_featured',
                            'value' => 1,
                        ),
                    ),
                );

                $listings = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I also see it defined as 'at_biz_dir' here:

```
if ( !defined('ATBDP_POST_TYPE') ) { define('ATBDP_POST_TYPE', 'at_biz_dir'); }
```

I AM able to spit out the values I'm looking for in part of a template file by over-riding it (similar to WooCommerce) to create custom ribbons for each listing plan type:

```
$listings->loop_thumb_card_template();
        $listings->render_loop_fields($loop_fields['thumbnail']['avatar']);
        
        
        
        /* START PA CUSTOM EDITS */
        $plan_id = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_fm_plans', true );
        if ($plan_id) {
        if ($plan_id == "13713") { $list_class = "gold";} 
        if ($plan_id == "13714") { $list_class = "silver";} 
        if ($plan_id == "13715") { $list_class = "bronze";} 
        if ($plan_id == "13716") { $list_class = "business";}
        } else {
            $plan_id = "";
            $list_class = "";
        }
        ?>
        <div class="<? echo($plan_id . " " . $list_class); ?> ribbon"><? echo($list_class); ?></div> 
<? /* END PA CUSTOM EDITS */ ?>
```

The edits are between the "PA CUSTOM EDIT" comments, but I want to have this custom post type query sort by that meta value so that Gold is first, followed by silver, and so on.

Here is what I've tried. All I get is a 404 page not found error.

```
// Function accepting current query
    function my_change_order( $listings ) {
        // Check if the query is for an archive
        //if($listings) {
            // Query was for archive, then set order
            $listings->set( 'post_type', ATBDP_POST_TYPE );
            $listings->set( 'orderby' , 'meta_value' );
            $listings->set( 'meta_key' , '_fm_plans' );
            $listings->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
        //} else {
            // Return the original query for non-archive pages
            return $listings;
        //}
        // Return the query
        return $listings;
    }
    // Runs before the posts are fetched
    add_filter( 'pre_get_posts' , 'my_change_order' );
```

I have also tried adding quotes to "ATBDP_POST_TYPE", and replacing it with "at_biz_dir". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what ended up working for me.

```
if (! is_admin()) {
function custom_at_biz_dir_query( $query ) {
    // Check if the query is for the custom post type at_biz_dir
    if ( isset( $query->query_vars['post_type'] ) && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'at_biz_dir' ) {
        // Order the posts by the presence of the _fm_plans meta_value
        $query->set( 'meta_key', '_fm_plans' );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num meta_value' );
        $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => '_fm_plans',
                'compare' => 'EXISTS',
                'type' => 'NUMERIC',
            ),
            array(
                'key' => '_fm_plans',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
            ),
        ) );
        $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_at_biz_dir_query' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the PHP error log or the WordPress debug log for any messages?

What happens if you update your `my_change_order` function with this?

```
function my_change_order( $query ) {
    // Check if the query is for the main listing archive
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && is_post_type_archive( ATBDP_POST_TYPE ) ) {
        // Set the order based on the meta value
        $query->set( 'meta_key', '_fm_plans' );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_change_order' );
```

Comment: Thank you. In the end, I posted a solution that best suited my needs.